# Adwords CSV import requires strange field that is not in documentation

Tags: csv, import, google-ads-api

As a refference I used https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuHDrmCX8MtydFdadzFHZVgzZXlpbW16Q283djZsRVE#gid=0
To create my own import to Adwords.

However i have some trouble because of errors. Tried to import this example CSV (from link above).

It has same problems, like my CSV.

Row #2:

```
Budget is missing when adding the campaign.
Campaign type is missing when adding the campaign.
Bidding strategy type is missing when adding the campaign.
```

Row #7

```
This row is missing a required value: 'Ad'.
```

Can't find those fields in documentation: https://support.google.com/adwords/editor/answer/57747?hl=en

What are those fields? What Value they expect? What is this CSV missing?

Answer (score 2):

That sample spreadsheet is for AdWords Editor, which is a standalone program for Windows or Mac. Unfortunately, Editor and the AdWords Web UI don't accept the same formats.

Here's the documentation for the Web-based upload: https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2477116?hl=en